# Unit testing a REST Get Api

Tags: java, rest, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am testing a GET rest api that I have written that when called with appropriate parameters returns a response like below :

```
[
  {
    "baseline": "tableName",
    "targetDataSource": "tableName",
    "status": "EQUALS"
  },
  {
    "baseline": "tableName",
    "targetDataSource": "tableName",
    "status": "EQUALS"
  }
]
```

Here is how I am unit testing it :

```
   String jsonResponse = "[" + "{\"baseline\" : \"tableName\",\"targetDataSource\": \"tableName\","
        + "\"status\": \"EQUALS\"},{ \"baseline\": \"tableName\",\"targetDataSource\": \"tableName\","
        + "\"status\": \"EQUALS\"}" + "]";
    List<MatchingResult> obj;
    ObjectMapper MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();
    obj = MAPPER.readValue(jsonResponse, new TypeReference<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>() {
    });

    when(matchingService.searchRowkeyAndMatch(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(obj);
    mockMvc.perform(get((MATCHING_GET_ENDPOINT), "123", "2016-08-12 11:33:11")).andExpect(status().isOk());
```

I am however receiving an Assertion Error. Status Expected<200> but was <404>.
I think I am doing it right way. Don't know what's going wrong.

`MatchingResult` is my `dto` which is as follows :

```
@Data
public class MatchingResult {
  String baseline;
  String targetDataSource;
  QueryResultStatusEnum status;
}
```

Here is my controller code:

```
  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/result/config/{date}",
      produces = OneplatformMediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
  @ApiOperation(value = "get result from matchingengine")
  @ApiResponses(value = {@ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Invalid input")})
  public ResponseEntity<List<MatchingResult>> getMatchingStatus(
      @ApiParam(value = "Name of the configuration", required = true) 
      @RequestParam("config") String configName,
      @ApiParam(value = "Date of the data", required = true) @PathVariable("date") String date) {
    String rowkey =
        new StringBuilder().append(configName).append("#").append("data").append("#")
            .append(date).toString();
    List<MatchingResult> searchRowkey = matchingService.searchRowkeyAndMatch(rowkey);
    if (searchRowkey.isEmpty()) {
      throw NotFoundException.builder().entityNotFound()
      .details("Rowkey not found.").build();
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(searchRowkey, HttpStatus.OK);

  }
```

And `MATCHING_GET_ENDPOINT` is

```
 MATCHING_GET_ENDPOINT = "/dataverification/v1/matchingApi/result/config/{date}";
```

Also, how can I verify one of the values of entities `baseline, targetDataSource and status` ?

Thanks

Comment: Post code of your controller. What is `MATCHING_GET_ENDPOINT`?

Comment: @OleksandrShpota I have added controller and `MATCHING_GET_ENDPOINT`